# What is the best way to count rows in spark data frame for monitoring?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, pyspark, monitoring

I have a pyspark application running on EMR for which I'd like to monitor some metrics.
For example count loaded, saved rows. Currently I use `count` operation to extract values, which, obviously, slows down the application. I was thinking whether there are a better options to extract those kind of metrics from dataframe?
I'm using pyspark 2.4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're counting the full dataframe, try [persisting](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.persist) the dataframe first, so that you don't have to run the computation twice.

If an approximate count is acceptable, you can [sample](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sample) before counting to speed things up.

```py
sample_fraction = 0.01 # take a roughly 1% sample
sample_count = df.sample(fraction=sample_fraction).count() # count the sample
extrapolated_count = sample_count / sample_fraction # estimate the total count
```

There's also an [`approx_count_distinct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.approx_count_distinct) function, if you need a count of distinct values for a particular column.

Answer (score 1):

If you need exact count then `use parquet` or `delta lake` format to store the data. It stores statistics so count results are fast (in seconds).

If you can live without exact count then you can use `Dataframe.isEmpty`, `Dataframe.first`, `Dataframe.head(<number of rows>)` etc to compensate for your needs.